# How to set the character encoding in a yaml file

Tags: character-encoding, yaml

We are working with the simple backend for the new Rails 2.2 i18n system, and I wanted to know the proper syntax for setting the encoding in a yaml file.

On other words what is the yaml for this xml:

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You *can't* define the encoding in YAML. But there's also no *need* to, since the encoding is done at the file level and is transparent to the YAML and its parsing. When writing a YAML document, this is all you need to remember.

On the file level, YAML 1.1 supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 but not UTF-32. The [full details of the 1.1 specification](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2513364) is that

> All characters [...] are Unicode code points. Each such code point is
>   written as one or more octets depending on the character encoding
>   used. Note that in UTF-16, characters above #xFFFF are written as four
>   octets, using a surrogate pair. A YAML processor must support the
>   UTF-16 and UTF-8 character encodings. If a character stream does not
>   begin with a byte order mark (#FEFF), the character encoding shall be
>   UTF-8. Otherwise it shall be either UTF-8, UTF-16 LE or UTF-16 BE as
>   indicated by the byte order mark. On output, it is recommended that a
>   byte order mark should only be emitted for UTF-16 character encodings.
>   Note that the UTF-32 encoding is explicitly not supported.

For YAML 1.2, [UTF-32 is supported](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2771184) as well.

Comment: this is very similar to JSON, for what that's worth (although JSON also allows UTF-32, doubt anyone uses it)

Comment: Actually, according to the JSON RFC, any Unicode format with a BOM is acceptable, and UTF-8 without a BOM. I'm surprised, though, that the JSON and YAML specifications mention this at all, since it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @bzlm No, it looks like only UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are [specifically enumerated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1).